# How to avoid nested query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I managed to write this query:

```
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
VALUES (@UserId, (SELECT Id FROM Roles WHERE Name = @Name));
```

And it works as intended. The problem is that I feel like this is a bad approach to write nested queries (here - find the id of a role in `Roles` table that matches the specified name). Is it possible to make this without the nested query?

Experienced programmers may laugh, but I am trying to learn this and I don't know how could I make this query better. I would be very grateful for your advice.

Comment: Why do you feel the "nested query" is a problem?  It seems like you don't want to use any query at all — how else would you get your information from `roles`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `INSERT` statement to be like below using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` construct. You may refer `Postgresql` documentation for more information on the same.

```
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
SELECT @UserId, Id FROM Roles WHERE Name = @Name;
```